# Extract items from a list in a vectorized way?

Tags: r, list

I'd like to extract all items from a list and give them novel names. Is there a simple way to do this? The result I want is possible in a tedious manual way as follows:

```
mylist = list(data.frame(seq(1,10,1)), data.frame(seq(40,50,1)), data.frame(seq(70,80,1)))

apples = mylist[[1]]
pears = mylist[[2]]
oranges = mylist[[3]]
```

However this becomes ever more tedious with larger lists or numbers of lists. I want to ask R,

"Please extract all the items in mylist to separate objects named c('apples','pears','oranges')."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply give your list names and use `list2env` to store each element in the global environment.

```
list2env(x = setNames(mylist, c('apples','pears','oranges')), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try ussing the `assign` function from `base`. It works by giving a string (name of the variable) and its content. You can loop it such as:

```
names # vector containing variables names
sapply(1:length(names),function(x){ assign(names[x],mylist[[x]]}
```